# Picture in picture with camera - iPad Pro

Tags: ipad, camera

I would like to know if it is possible to have a floating window with the image that the camera is showing, that is, to have a small window on the screen that is showing what the camera sees, it is not necessary to record, only to see what what does the camera show (like a picture in picture, but without video, i want to see what its camera sees)

Comment: Are you looking for an app or is this a question about how to code a window like this?

Comment: Just an app, a want to have a small window on screen to sees the camera when use other apps, games, and other apps